# KVM is not available Arm64

Tags: ubuntu, arm64

I am using M2 processor.

When trying to create a new virtual machine,  I am getting KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly.

Connection: QEMU/KVM

I have tried

lsmod | grep kvm

and. sudo apt-get install kvm qemu. It didn't work for me

Comment: You tagged your question `[ubuntu]`, but so far only Asahi Linux supports Apple Silicon chips, so you're omitting critical information here. How did you install Ubuntu on M2?

Comment: So, I used UTM box for installation of ubuntu server on ARM64.

Comment: So you want nested virtualization. While M2 supports that in hardware, hypervisors that want to use this would currently have to resort to unstable APIs in order to make use of it.